# ArcGIS deep learning failed. Invalid band index encountered. [requested band 3 at position 3]

Tags: deep-learning, arcgis

I am trying to follow the ArcGIS tutorial [Cloud Mask Generation (Sentinel-2)](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/pretrained-models/latest/imagery/using-cloud-mask-generation-sentinel-2-.htm).

I downloaded a tiff image (shared using Dropbox) [image](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/625t5r0oqkih6s4t0g5lk/2023-09-29-00_00_2023-09-29-23_59_Sentinel-2_L2A_True_color.tiff?rlkey=cr3y5a71qzt88r7b9de5qy29l&dl=0) data from Copernicus.

I set all parameters the same as the tutorial, but the model fails to run and says:

[image]

But my data does have 3 bands, like shown in:
[image]

Any suggestions?